# Analyzing Gmail Logs in BigQuery

Tags: email, logging, google-bigquery, gmail

I am trying to determine the total amount of messages sent from my G Suite account.  I am streaming my logs to BigQuery.

Messages may appear in the logs multiple times so I can count the distinct message headers.

```
SELECT 
count (DISTINCT message_info.rfc2822_message_id) as MessageIDCount
FROM `my data set`
```

This would count total inbound and outbound, so if I only want outbound I can add WHEN message_info.message_set.type = 8.

But the Sending Limits for gmail https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491#sendinglimitsforrelay

The sending limits are not just total messages sent it counts based on the number of recipients.

I am interested in running a query that will provide total number of messages sent where if I sent an email to 2 people it would count as 2, If I sent to 10 it would count as 10, etc.

Essentially I want to determine how close I was to hitting sending limits for a given day.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the format of the "to:" field? I guess you are asking "how to count how many recipients" each mail has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_info.timestamp_usec)) day,
  COUNT(address) AS total_recipients  
FROM `project.dataset.gmail_log`, 
UNNEST(message_info.destination) AS destination
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(message_info.message_set) WHERE type = 8)
GROUP BY day
```

it will return daily total number of recipients in below format

```
Row day         total_recipients     
1   2019-01-10  100  
2   2019-01-11  100  
3   2019-01-12  100  
4   2019-01-13  100  
5   2019-01-14  100
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail super helpful

Comment: Glad it helped. I did it blindly :o) but was pretty sure it is correct one